Group visually aligned data from text by label and value in Python
I have an array of arrays containing data in the following format:
text_lines = [
['Datum puštanja u', '', '', '', '', '  Odobreni limit u CURR', ' Tekuća klasifikacija', '', '', 'Tekuća CKKL', '   Dani', '', '  Iznos otplaćivanja u CURR', '', '', 'Naziv institucije i']
    ['realizaciju', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' klasifikacija', ' kašnjenja', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' broj']
    ['13.08.1999.', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '   130.000,00', 'A', '', '', '', '', '', '', '   S1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  100,50', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  PLACEHOLDER NAME DD']
    ['Datum otplate', '', '', '', '', '', '   Neiskorišteni iznos', ' Prethodna klasifikacija', '', ' Prethodna CKKL', '', '', '', '  Žirant vraća kredit', '', '', '', ' 338-123412412-43']
    ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'limita u CURR', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'klasifikacija', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '   Razlog gašenja']
    ['10.09.1999.', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '   0,00  B', '', '', '', '', '', '', '   S1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  Completed']
    ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' Dospjela nenaplaćena', '   Datum promjene', '', '', '', '  Datum promjene CKKL']
    ['Stvarni datum zatvaranja', '', '', '', '  glavnica/kamata u', ' klasifikacije', '', '', '', '   klasifikacije', '', '', '', '   Datum i vrijeme ažuriranja']
    ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' CURR']
    ['07.09.1999.', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 0,00/0,00   07.07.1999.', '', '', '', '', ' 07.02.1999.', '', '', '', '', ' 12.09.1999. 13:10']
]

As you can notice, there is a label and value directly underneath. The label can span over multiple lines and so can the value.
By looking at it you can extract and notice the values that are defined underneath, but trying to split the data by characters or aligning it by index and trying to do the same will not work in this case. Values can be empty, indicated by an empty string.
In the above situation I have 7 columns in the first row, 6 in the second and 5 in third.
I need to group this data by label, considering that the value may be null (an empty line). How can I achieve this in Python and is it even possible without messing up the data?

Actually, no, most of us probably cannot notice that because we don't understand the language, so we cannot see, how the data actually belongs together (ie, what is a label and what is a value). If the first row is supposed to contain labels (and the first colum seems to be a date) why are there so mny empty strings in the first row. And why is the first value of the second row a string and not a date? Maybe you could simplify your example and also provide the expected result from your grouping?

Aside: That's a list of lists, not an array of arrays. Python's array module is a different beast.
